# Programmatically block caller ID from an iOS application

Tags: ios, phone-call

Since *67 doesn't work when embedding in phone links is there a way to programmatically block caller ID from an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You do not have access to the phone application, or any other application outside your app.